# How to request payments from multiple users on Paypal?

Tags: paypal

So, we have multiple subscribers to our product (we have their emails). Till now we had just sent invoice to customers email addresses and waited for payment.

I know that all customers have paypal. Now I want to charge monthly through paypal. Is there a way I can charge multiple users at once? Something like mass charging - opposite of mass payments? Customers aren't subscribed through paypal, we just have their email addresses of paypal.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such functionality.
You'll always need explicit permission from a user. Or in other words; they'll need to 'subscribe' to it.

Easiest way would be to create a subscription button via https://www.paypal.com/buttonfactory/ , ensure you're logged in to your PayPal account and get the 'Email' link (shown at the end) and send this out via email to all customers.

Comment: What about Paypal Recurring payments?

Comment: Same answer (unless you have their credit card details, which you said you don't).